# Logistic regression log-likelihood - meaning of μ

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, notation

I'm trying to implement my own logistic regression, but I'm not sure I understand some of the notation. In Machine Learning : A Probabilistic Perspective (Murphy, 2012), the negative log-likelihood is written (eq 8.3, pg 246):

$ NLL = -\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left[ y_{i}log\mu_{i} + (1 - y_{i})log(1-\mu_{i}) \right] $

I'm confused by what $\mu$ represents in this equation. Is it the mean of something? If so, what?

Answer (score 0):

It is the *conditional* mean (of the response, given the covariates). I.e. if $Y$ is the response, and $\underline{X}$ is the vector of predictors, then $$\mu_i=\mathbb{E}\left(Y\mid\underline{X}=\underline{X}_i\right).$$ Note that as $Y$ is assumed to have Bernoulli distribution, this mean is also the (conditional) probability that $Y$ takes the value of 1.